# java.lang.Comparable and equals

Tags: java, equals, comparable

If I implement `java.lang.Comparable` for a class, do I still have to override the `equals()` method? Or will the `Comparable` work for `equals` as well?

If the answer is **no**, then what if some discrepancy arises? Let's say the way I term two objects as equal within the `equals()` method is different from the way I term two objects of the same class as equal within the `compareTo()` of the `Comparable`.

Moreover, if I implement `Comparable`, do I also have to override `equals()`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

While it is recommended (and pretty sensible) that having `a.compareTo(b) == 0` imply that `a.equals(b)` (and visa versa), it is *not* required. `Comparable` is intended to be used when performing an ordering on a series of objects, whereas `equals()` just tests for straight equality.

[This link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10) has some good information on implementing `compareTo` properly.

Comment: +1 here's a link to the relevant Effective Java's chapters (see item 11) http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf

Comment: @MByD Thanks for the link. It (unsurprisingly) says it better than I do!

Comment: @MbyD thanks for the link. Is it ok to call a.compareTo(b) or compare() directly?

Comment: @aps - why wouldn't it be? please note - if you override the equals() method, you should also **must** override the hashCode() method.

Comment: @aps If at some point in your code you would like to know how `a` compares to `b`, then you can go right ahead.

Comment: Ok. So, I have a class with a natural ordering which I have specified using the Comparable interface. Now I want to see how two objects of that class compares with each other based on some other criteria. So should I just create an object of a class which implements Comparator and create a new object of that class, and then call compare(o1,o2)?

Comment: @aps: Yep, implementing `Comparator` is what you do when the comparison you want to make doesn't follow the natural order of the class.

Comment: @aps When you say "based on some other criteria", do you mean different than the natural order you've imposed? If so, then creating a `Comparator` is the way to go.

Comment: I don't want to sort the whole collection, just see how two objects compare.

Comment: @aps That's fine. `Comparator` just defines a two-argument `compare()` method; you can call it on your objects and inspect the result.

Answer (score 8):

From Javadoc of [java.lang.Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals.

Answer (score 5):

While it is recommended, it is not required that `.equals()` and `.compareTo()` have the same behaviour.

Just look at the [BigDecimal Docs for equals() method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal
> only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to
> 2.00 when compared by this method).

BigDecimal is a core class of java that has different behaviour for `equals()` and `compareTo()` and serves as a good example of the difference between 2 objects that are comparable vs truly equal.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say the way I term two objects as equal within the equals()
>   method is different from the way I term two objects of the same class
>   as equal within the toCompare() of the Comparable?

If you do this, and you put those objects into a **sorted set**, the set will misbehave. [From the docs on SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an
>   explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if the
>   sorted set is to correctly implement the Set interface.

For example, a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) may (erroneously) contain two objects where

```
a.compareTo(b) != 0
```

even though

```
a.equals(b) == true
```

Comment: All `TreeSet` operations are performed using `compareTo` - so objects that the comparison returns `!= 0` are considered distinct, and objects that the comparison returns `== 0` are identical (and thus only the first one added to the set is actually retained).  As the Javadoc says: `The behavior of a sorted set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.`

Comment: People regularly get bitten by this behaviour of `TreeSet`: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22123336/587365 https://stackoverflow.com/q/11082197/587365 https://stackoverflow.com/q/23489718/587365