# why does TreeSet remove duplicates when they are unequal?

Tags: java, collections

Friends, I am having a problem in getting entire data using `TreeSet`. I have sorted the `TreeSet` on some same values.

here is my code:

`MyCars` class:

```
class MyCars implements Comparable<MyCars>{

    private String number;
    private int yearModel;
    private double horsePower;

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public int getYearModel() {
        return yearModel;
    }
    public void setYearModel(int yearModel) {
        this.yearModel = yearModel;
    }
    public double getHorsePower() {
        return horsePower;
    }
    public void setHorsePower(double horsePower) {
        this.horsePower = horsePower;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyCars c) {
        return Double.compare(this.horsePower,c.getHorsePower());
    }
}
```

`SortTest` class:

```
public class SortTest {

    void GoForSort(){
        Set dataStructure=new TreeSet();

        MyCars c1=new MyCars();
        c1.setNumber("SRT-Viper123");
        c1.setYearModel(2013);
        c1.setHorsePower(450.00);

        MyCars c2=new MyCars();
        c2.setNumber("Chevrolet-Corvette901");
        c2.setYearModel(2012);
        c2.setHorsePower(450.00);

        MyCars c3=new MyCars();
        c3.setNumber("Ford-Mustang678");
        c3.setYearModel(2014);
        c3.setHorsePower(455.00);

        dataStructure.add(c1);
        dataStructure.add(c2);
        dataStructure.add(c3);

        Iterator<MyCars> it=dataStructure.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            MyCars c=it.next();
            System.out.println(c.getNumber()+"\t"+c.getHorsePower()+"\t"+c.getYearModel());
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortTest st=new SortTest();
        st.GoForSort();

    }

}
```

As you can see I have sorted the `TreeSet` on the basis of horsePower. And I have given SAME value for horse-power to two objects.

Here is the output I get:

```
SRT-Viper123    450.0   2013
Ford-Mustang678 455.0   2014
```

But I also want `Chevrolet-Corvette901` to come in this set of output. Why I am not getting it.

Is there any way to include that also? Because I found there was NO Problem when I change my collection to `ArrayList`. Does `TreeSet` sorts only unique elements?

Is there any trick to get & print all objects during `Iteration` regardless of their uniqueness in `TreeSet`...

Comment: The definition of a Set is that is doesn't store duplicates elements. Since you're definition of unique is only based on the horsepower you can't have your Corvette car in the Set.

Comment: A set by definition can not have duplicate entries.

Comment: Most of the answerers haven't read the question thoroughly. The issue here is not with the general contract of Set. The OP hasn't defined `equals()` so all objects in the set are necessarily unequal. The question is then, why does the TreeSet still coalesce elements?

Comment: @AndrewSpencer thanks for noticing this correctly. Came across to this issue after 7 years. I am still confused. Does compareTo method internally works like overridden equals method?

Comment: @JPG not sure what you're asking. You're defining the `compareTo()` so it only looks at horsepower. You haven't defined `equals()` so you get the default, which is instance equality. So in your example, two MyCars with same horsepower are not equal by `equals()` method, but `compareTo()` returns 0 and TreeSet understands this to mean "they are equal".

Comment: If you would define `equals()` to be `return ((MyCars) other).horsePower == this.horsePower` then you would also get the observed behaviour with other Set implementations such as `HashSet`.

Comment: BTW to get the output you want, you should add extra cases to `compareTo` so that, if result is zero, then you instead return `Integer.compare(this.yearModel, other,yearModel)` and if that also is zero, you return `String.compare(this.number, other.number)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally with a `Set`, the uniqueness of the contained objects is determined by their `equals()` method. In your example, you would implement `Car.equals()` such that two Cars would be equal if they had the same number, modelYear and horsePower. Then you could add your Corvette into the set and it wouldn't conflict with another model that has the same horsepower.

`TreeSet` is different: it determines that two objects are identical, not when `equals()` returns `true`, but when the `compareTo()` returns 0. This means you can easily find yourself with two objects that the TreeSet treats as identical, even though they aren't.

Indeed the doc for `TreeSet` states:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface.

In other words, **to not break the Set contract, TreeSet depends on YOU only ever supplying a `Comparator` that's consistent with the `equals()` implementation of the objects you put in the set**.

Since TreeSet allows you to specify an arbitrary `Comparator`, we might as well be more succinct and say that TreeSet breaks the Set contract.

Comment: Thank You for the explanation.. So `TreeSet` breaks the `Set` contract because it secretly prohibits duplicates (as according to you, `compareTo` returning 0 for identical objects) even when we not override `equals` method in our Foo,Bar classes.

Comment: Yes but TreeSet will respect the Set contract if you define an `equals()` method consistent with what you put in `compareTo()`. But you will still have your problem, unless you complete your `equals()` and `compareTo()` to also check values of the 2 other fields cf my comment under the question. Not sure if this is still useful after 7 years...

Answer (score 4):

`TreeSet` is a child of `Set` and sets do not store duplicate values. Here is the first line from the definition of set in [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

**Edit:**
As pointed out by @AlexEfimov in the comment below, [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) uses the `compareTo` method to determine the ordering and equality of elements, and so as others have pointed out, the `compareTo` implementation of `MyCars` would make the two elements with the same horse power equal, and hence only one of them would be stored in the `TreeSet`.

Comment: This answer causes confusion! `TreeSet` uses `compareTo` for determining equity, not `equals`!

Comment: @AlexEfimov, right, sorry about my previous answer, I was just trying to point out that since `TreeSet` was a child of `Set`, equal elements would be removed. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Make your `compareTo` also compare the `number` and `yearModel` fields.
2. Store a collection (array or `List`) at each node - usually called a [MultiSet](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

So long as your `compareTo` reports that two items are equal, **only one of them** will appear in the set.

Comment: Thank You. First option solved my option. `@Override
 public int compareTo(MyCars c) {
  if (this.horsePower < c.getHorsePower()) return -1;
  if (this.horsePower > c.getHorsePower()) return 1;
  return this.number.compareTo(c.getNumber());
 }`

Comment: Note that this behaviour is specific to `TreeSet` and differs from the general behaviour of `Set` in Java (where the contained objects' `equals()` method is used to determine uniqueness)

Answer (score 1):

Set doesn't store duplicated elements. 
If you want to store both of your cars you should change `equals` and `compareTo` methods to compare also number. Then both entries will be different.

Remember that `equals` method should be consistent with `compareTo`, so I strongly recommend you to override equals method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sets only store unique elements.

Comment: +1 This is not something Java made up to annoy people.  The general definition of a "Set" has unique elements http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia on a [Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29)

> In mathematics, a set is a collection of distinct objects, considered as an object in its own right. For example, the numbers 2, 4, and 6 are distinct objects when considered separately, but when they are considered collectively they form a single set of size three, written {2,4,6}. Sets are one of the most fundamental concepts in mathematics.

A `Set` has distinct/unique elements, i.e. no duplicates.