# demonstrate that equals goes hand in hand with compareTo

Tags: java, equals, comparable, compareto

It's written in all decent java courses, that if you implement the `Comparable` interface, you should (in most cases) **also** override the `equals` method to match its behavior.

Unfortunately, in my current organization people try to convince me to do exactly the opposite. I am **looking for the most convincing code example** to show them all the evil that will happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.Comparable and equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970879/java-lang-comparable-and-equals)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can beat them by showing the [Comparable javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Comparable.html) that says:

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural
>   orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets
>   (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when
>   they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted
>   map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined
>   in terms of the equals method.
>
> For example, if one adds two keys a and b such that (!a.equals(b) &&
>   a.compareTo(b) == 0) to a sorted set that does not use an explicit
>   comparator, the second add operation returns false (and the size of
>   the sorted set does not increase) because a and b are equivalent from
>   the sorted set's perspective.

So especially with SortedSet (and SortedMap) if the `compareTo` method returns 0, it assumes it as equal and doesn't add that element second time even the the `equals` method returns false, and causes confusion as specified in the [SortedSet javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an
>   explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if the
>   sorted set is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See the
>   Comparable interface or Comparator interface for a precise definition
>   of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is
>   defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted set performs
>   all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so
>   two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the
>   standpoint of the sorted set, equal. The behavior of a sorted set is
>   well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just
>   fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.

Comment: Once forgot to override the equals method, and to debug this intermittent problem was not nice.

Comment: Good quotes, however, I think your comments about `SortedSet` interface is not correct. (It's the other way round) e.g. a `TreeSet` (which is a `SortedSet`) can contain 2 objects `a` and `b` even when `a.equals(b) == true`.

Comment: @bvdb I believe I got it right. The javadoc for Comparable interface does say that `For example, if one adds two keys a and b such that (!a.equals(b) && a.compareTo(b) == 0) to a sorted set that does not use an explicit comparator, the second add operation returns false (and the size of the sorted set does not increase) because a and b are equivalent from the sorted set's perspective.`

Answer (score 5):

If you don't override the `equals` method, it inherits its behaviour from the `Object` class.
This method returns `true` if and only if the specified object is not null and refers to the same instance.

Suppose the following class:

```
class VeryStupid implements Comparable
{
  public int x;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(VeryStupid o)
  {
    if (o != null)
      return (x - o.x);
    else
      return (1);
  }
}
```

We create 2 instances:

```
VeryStupid one = new VeryStupid();
VeryStupid two = new VeryStupid();
one.x = 3;
two.x = 3;
```

The call to `one.compareTo(two)` returns 0 indicating the instances are equal but the call to `one.equals(two)` returns false indicating they're not equal.
This is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

Consistency of `compareTo` and `equals` is not required but strongly recommended.

I'll give it a shot with this example:

```
private static class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object _other) {
        System.out.println("equals");
        return super.equals(_other);
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Foo _other) {
        System.out.println("compareTo");
        return 0;
    }
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Foo a, b;

    a = new Foo();
    b = new Foo();

    a.compareTo(b);  // prints 'compareTo', returns 0 => equal
    a.equals(b);     // just prints 'equals', returns false => not equal 
}
```

You can see that your (maybe very important and complicated) comparission code is ignored when you use the default `equals`-method.

Comment: Well you have an example on that are not related, but you don't describe why it is important that they are implemented the same way.

Answer (score 0):

the method `int compareTo(T o)` allow you know if the `T o` is (in some way) superior or inferior of `this`, so it allow you to order a list of `T o`. 
In the scenario of `int compareTo(T o)` you have to do :

- is o InstanceOfThis ? => true/false ;
- is o EqualOfThis ? => true/false ;
- is o SuperiorOfThis ? => true/false ;
- is o InferiorOfThis ? true/false ;

So you see you have the equality test, and the best way to not implement the equality two times is to put it in the `boolean equals(Object obj)` method.